# In Gmail, is there a way to print a message without the Google logo?

Tags: gmail, printing

In Gmail, whenever you go to print a message, gmail adds a "Gmail by Google" logo to the top of the page being printed. Is there a way to print without this Logo?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best and simple way is **just select the part of the message** you want to print, then right click **and select print**.

Comment: You, my friend, just saved a acre of forest that would otherwise be printed in my company :)

Comment: This should have been marked as the answer. It's easy and doesn't require fiddling with the Developer's Tools or adding an extension.

Comment: For years, I've been selecting text and not right-clicking within the selection to print. Then had to use "more options" then tick "print selection".

Comment: This answer is specific to Chrome.

Comment: I've joined this SE just to upvote this. You've changed my life forever.

Answer (score 9):

Best way of doing it is to open developer tools (mostly key f12 on windows machine). Hover mouse pointer on element and delete its corresponding html in opened web tools. This can be extended for pages not having 'print' view CSS and showing sidebars etc., layout required for print can be changed.

Answer (score 8):

I have just created a [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en-CA/chrome/browser/) extension that will remove the Gmail logo from the top of the print screen automatically! Give it is a try: [Email Print Page Cleaner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-print-page-cleaner/hbcdmmaobjagbplobejomeefggahclkf?hl=en-US&gl=CA).

Let me know if there are any issues. It is fairly simple so there should not be any problems. The source for it is on [Github](https://github.com/Fogest/Gmail-Print-Page-Cleaner), so feel free to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Use any [Adblock browser extension](https://adblockplus.org/en/chrome) to block the `<DIV>` element or the actual image file. This has the advantage that you only need to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to print as a .pdf and use adobe acrobat to remove the images.

Another way is to printscreen if it's only part of a page, align it on a paper sized document (in an online image editor - 8x10 inches or whatever) and paint white over what you don't want.

Another way is to 'save as' in html and open it up in notepad and remove the image link (It will start with  and you remove from the < to the >.

There are probably a few other ways, it took me two seconds with a "print to .pdf program installed where you select something called 'pdf printer' instead of whatever actual printer you have set, you edit the .pdf and then you print the .pdf. I did this in adobe acrobat though there are probably free .pdf editors, I just don't have one. The print to .pdf is a free third party program that adds it to the printers.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome/Firefox/IE hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, navigate to the console tab and paste the following, then hit return.

```
$('.bodycontainer table').remove();
$('.bodycontainer hr').remove();
$('.bodycontainer table').remove();
$('.bodycontainer hr').remove();
$('.bodycontainer table tr:first-child').remove();
$('.bodycontainer table tr:first-child').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Print Gmail without logo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-gmail-without-logo/niooegglpelonkgbeejcplccleadcfdc), another chrome extension that uses CSS for hiding the logo instead of using JavaScript, so the logo will be hidden before it is rendered (i.e., no flickering).

Answer (score 0):

I have also discovered that if you use [Google Apps for Work](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/), Google's paid version of Gmail allows you to upload your own company logo and that custom logo will appear instead.

Answer (score -3):

use windows snipping tool in region mode and print it as an image.